# Google Vision, ImageAnnotatorClient error: code: 3, message: "Bad image data."

Tags: python-3.x, image, base64, google-cloud-vision

Getting `Bad image data` when trying to detect text in a part (numpy array rectangle out) of an opencv image. When I try to convert the resulting base64 string online it works without issues [(here for example)](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter)

```
im = Image.fromarray(narray.astype("uint8"))
rawBytes = io.BytesIO()
im.save(rawBytes, "PNG")
rawBytes.seek(0)  # return to the start of the file
image = vision.types.Image(content = b64encode(rawBytes.read()))
resp = client.text_detection(image = image)
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51735897/google-cloud-vision-api-error-code-3-message-bad-image-data) on the topic but why would I need to do that?

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?